# Creating a scala Reader from a file

Tags: scala

How do you instantiate a *scala.util.parsing.input.Reader* to read from a file? The API mentions in passing something about PagedSeq and java.io.Reader, but it's not clear at all how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You create a FileInputStream, pass that to an InputStreamReader and pass that to the apply method of the StreamReader companion object, which returns a StreamReader, a subtype of Reader.

```
scala> import scala.util.parsing.input.{StreamReader,Reader}
import scala.util.parsing.input.{StreamReader, Reader}

scala> import java.io._
import java.io._

scala> StreamReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test")))
res0: scala.util.parsing.input.StreamReader = scala.util.parsing.input.StreamReader@1e5a0cb
```

Comment: I just feel I need to point out that this will load the whole file in memory, which can be an issue.